authorization issue when try to send message using python (msal or msgraph library)?
I have a Python script to send messages using msgraph, but I can't do it because I have an authorization issue, but when I get a token directly on the msgraph site I can do it, but I try to get the token using my python script the token don't have permission to send message.
For this, I can see that I have some privileges permission, I registered an APP and gave a lot of permissions (30) including team migration. What are all the privileges I can attribute to my registered app?
As I told you, when I change the token and use a msgraph site token my code sends a message, when I try to get the token using the code, the token received doesn't have permission to send a message.
This code gets a token, but this token doesn't have permission to send a message and I have the error:
401
{
  "error":
    {
      "code":"Unauthorized",
      "message":"Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes."
    }
}

but using the same code, but using a token that I get on the msgraph site and using this token, and I can send messages normally.
example code to get token:
    # Set up the MSAL confidential client
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
    scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=client_secret
    )
    # Acquire a token
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    if "access_token" in result:
        access_token = result["access_token"]

